# Elasticsearch cluster metadata and document searching

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I'm trying to understand how a search query works. Based on the docs, whenever I query an elasticsearch node,

- Search request hits a node
- The node broadcasts this request to every shard in the index (either a primary or replica shard)
- Each shard performs the search query and responds with results
- Results are merged on the gateway node, sorted and returned to the user

(src: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/customizing-your-document-routing/ )

When I query a node, how does it know which shards are stored on machines? (I'm trying to understand point number 2)

**Where does the cluster metadata live? On everynode?**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Cluster State](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-state.html) and [routing](http://exploringelasticsearch.com/book/advanced-techniques/routing.html).

Comment: So each time I query a node, the master is contacted? I seem to had read that, the master is not a single point  of failure, and it need not be checked every time I query? I want to find out what happens each time I query  a node?